# Adding css classes dynamically to viewChild element

Tags: css, angular, viewchild

I want to add a class on blur to a child element of `<ng-select>`, which of course is not present in the html because it's compiled.

The child element is this one : 
    `.ng-select > .ng-select-container .ng-has-value`

I have tried :

In CSS file :

```
    :host>>>.ng-select .ng-select-container .ng-has-value {
        padding-top: 8px !important;
    }
```

In Typescript file :
adding class with ngClass directive don't work.

and this : but i can't select the right element (nativeElement undefined)

```
@ViewChild('select')
select: ElementRef;

let a = this.select.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('ng-select.ng-select-container')[0];
a.nativeElement.classList.add('paddingCenter');
```

I need to apply the padding top on this div (the first div inside ng-select):

```
<ng-select _ngcontent-c4 class="ng-select ... >
    <div class="ng-select-container ng-has-value">
          ...
    </div>
</ng-select>
```

EDIT : I found my mistake, it's now resolved. It was my css rule that wasn't good enough: i had this

```
:host>>>.ng-select > ng-select-container .ng-has-value {
}
```

which refered to

```
  <element :host>
     <element class="ng-select">
        <element class="ng-select-container">
           …
             <element class="ng-has-value">
```

So i changed it to `:host>>>.ng-select > div.ng-select-container.ng-has-value`
Which refers to what I want :

```
<element :host>
  <element class="ng-select">
    <div class="ng-select-container ng-has-value">
```

Comment: Why not use a css psedo selector `:first` or `nth-child()` ?

Comment: Try `::ng-deep .ng-select .ng-select-container .ng-has-value` for your css rule

Comment: Thank you. ::ng-deep didn't work, :first didn't actually work, i need to apply it on the second, nth-child(1n) or nth-child(2n) should have worked but didn't apply on the children..